# Create View With CASE Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using the WideWorldImporters database, which contains a table of binary values showing whether someone is an employee, if they can logon, and if they are a salesperson. I'm trying to create a view to display a friendlier version of the data.

Here are the relevant fields from the Application.People table:
[image]

And here's my attempted code:

```
CREATE VIEW Application.PeopleEmployeeStatus1
AS
    SELECT 
        PersonId, FullName, 
        IsPermittedToLogon, IsEmployee, IsSalesPerson,
        CASE 
            WHEN IsPermittedToLogon = 1 
               THEN 'Can Logon'
               ELSE 'Can''t Logon' 
        END AS LogonRights,
        CASE 
            WHEN IsEmployee = 1 AND IsSalesPerson = 1
               THEN 'SalesPerson'
            WHEN IsEmployee = 1
               THEN 'Regular'
            ELSE 'Not Employee' 
        END AS EmployeeType
    FROM 
        Application.People;
```

I'm getting the error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PeopleEmployeeStatus1, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: Your select looks fine to me, something else must be going on.  Is that view name valid?

Comment: The view is valid and works when I create it and then execute query `SELECT * FROM Application.PeopleEmployeeStatus1;`. My guess is you have other queries involved you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there are multiple statements involved:

```
-- here goes batch separator
GO

CREATE VIEW Application.PeopleEmployeeStatus1
AS
SELECT PersonId, FullName, 
    IsPermittedToLogon, IsEmployee, IsSalesPerson,
    CASE WHEN IsPermittedToLogon = 1 THEN 'Can Logon'
        ELSE 'Can''t Logon' END AS LogonRights,
    CASE WHEN IsEmployee = 1 and IsSalesPerson = 1
            THEN 'SalesPerson'
        WHEN IsEmployee = 1
            THEN 'Regular'
        ELSE 'Not Employee' END AS EmployeeType
FROM Application.People;
GO
```